# Entity framework core, использовать include с условием

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Необходимо скачать из базы данных сущности диалогов вместе с последним сообщением. Такой код не работает:

```
_dbContext.Dialogs
    .Where(_ => _.Users.Any(ud => ud.ApplicationUserId == userId))
    .Include(_ => _.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == _.Messages.Max(mm => mm.Id)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Ошибка: `The Include property lambda expression is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'.`

Как мне скачать одним запросом диалоги только последними сообщениями?

Comment: "Проблема молотка"? Зачем вам include с условием?

Comment: Перенести условие в Where. Приведите классы ваших сущностей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если условие только одно - можно развернуть связь:

```
_dbContext.Messages
    .Where(_ => m.Id == _.Dialog.Messages.Map(mm => nn.Id))
    .Where(_ => _.Dialog.Users.Any(ud => ud.ApplicationUserId == userId))
    .Include(_ => _.Dialog)
    .ToListAsync();
```

В более сложных случаях вы можете загрузить анонимный класс:

```
_dbContext.Dialogs
    .Where(_ => _.Users.Any(ud => ud.ApplicationUserId == userId))
    .SelectMany(_ => new { 
        dialog = _,
        message = _.Messages.Where(m => m.Id == _.Messages.Max(mm => mm.Id))).FirstOrDefault(),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

PS вот такая проверка - `m.Id == _.Messages.Max(mm => mm.Id)` однажды может стать убийцей производительности, осторожнее с ней.

Comment: а что можно использовать вместо Messages.Max?

Comment: К примеру, можно хранить номер последнего сообщения в таблице диалогов, а обновлять его триггером. Иногда это быстрее чем каждый раз искать максимум (а иногда - медленнее)

Comment: Почему не отсортировать по id и не взять первый?

Comment: @Anamnian потому что это работает для одного сообщения, а не для одного из каждого диалога

Comment: "потому что это работает для одного сообщения, а не для одного из каждого диалога " Вы в коде применяете max к связанной коллекции диалога, что мешает вам применить orderby к этой коллекции?

Comment: @Anamnian потому что это не мой код? :-)